# Fullscreen API: Which events are fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullscreen, jquery-events

I need to know which (DOM) events are fired when a user enter the fullscreen mode via the new [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode). I tried for example this snippet but it doesn't fire:

```
jQuery('body').on('fullScreenChange', function() { alert("Fired!"); });
```

Comment: Which browser, which version, which OS? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode#AutoCompatibilityTable Do you use the latest jQuery?

Comment: Note that despite the answers here, the event doesn't fire when hitting F11, as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21118401/345716)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your link [shows the answer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode#Notification)...

> When full-screen mode is successfully engaged, the document which contains the full-screen element receives a `fullscreenchange` event. When full-screen mode is exited, the document again receives a  `fullscreenchange` event. Note that the `fullscreenchange` event doesn't provide any information itself as to whether the document is entering or exiting full-screen mode, but if the document has a non null `fullScreenElement` , you know you're in full-screen mode.

Comment: FWIW, this only works when entering/exiting full screen with the Fullscreen API. If you enter full screen from your browser's toolbar, for example, the event won't fire.

Answer (score 66):

I was using:

```
$(document).on('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange MSFullscreenChange', fn);
```

It fires for Safari, Chrome, and Firefox (haven't tested others).
There seems to be a subtle difference in the resulting context between webkit and moz,
element height and width are different. But the events fire, which is your question.

Oh. And watch out for using `alert('fs')` with full screen testing. It often interferes with the screen change.

Comment: re 'on' vs 'bind'. I kept both, but in the edit lost the nick of the original correcting editor. Sorry.

Comment: webkitfullscreenchange doesn't fire for me in Safari when using Vimeo in an iframe. It works in chrome.

Comment: It has been so, long, I forget what events I had in the list and which not. It seems Kingpin2k has edited the event list in this answer, I hope for the better!

Comment: On older versions of Safari iOS, I had to use: `$('video').on("webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange MSFullscreenChange webkitbeginfullscreen webkitendfullscreen", foo)`

Answer (score 3):

There is [no fullscreenChange event in native jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=fullscreen). But there are several third-party plugins which provide you access to the event:

- http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/
- https://github.com/ruidlopes/jquery-fullscreen/blob/master/jquery.fullscreen.js
- https://github.com/hdragomir/jQuery-Fullscreen-Event
- https://github.com/ruidlopes/jquery-fullscreen

As you can see on their code there is no clean API access to this type of event.