# FullScreenChange event not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullscreen

I try bind FullScreenChange event, but it not work. Maybe i did something wrong?

```
$(document).bind('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange',function(){
if(document.fullScreen){
    console.log('Go to Full Screen mode');
    }else{
    console.log('Exit Full Screen mode');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably need to use the vendor specific prefix for the `document.fullScreen` property

```
var isFullScreen = document.fullScreen || 
                   document.mozFullScreen || 
                   document.webkitIsFullScreen;
```

Further information available here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode

Comment: But how can you listen for entering/exiting fullscreen?

Comment: @Dusty https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/onfullscreenchange

Comment: @Dusty: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621499/fullscreen-api-which-events-are-fired

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
window.onresize = resize
function resize() {
  //code
}
```