# Fullscreen API and keyUp event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Fullscreen API in Chrome and FF providing a button for the user to switch with code like this:

```
function initFullscreen() {
    $('#fullscreen').on('click', function(e) {
        requestFullscreen();
        $('#fullscreen').fadeOut();
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        // esc
        if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
            $('#fullscreen').fadeIn();
        }   
    });
}
```

When in fullscreen mode the button disappears, but clicking ESC brings the button back only if I click ESC a second time when already in normal mode again.

Anyone with an idea why keyup handler is not triggered in fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 0):

This does not really answer your specific question, but you could try another solution which should be even better than yours. There are other ways than <kbd>ESC</kbd> for exiting the fullscreen mode:

> In addition, navigating to another page, changing tabs, or switching
> to another application (using, for example, Alt-Tab) while in
> fullscreen mode exits fullscreen mode as well.
>
> — [MDN: Using fullscreen mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FUsing_full_screen_mode)

You should therefore listen to the official event:

> #### Notification
>
> When fullscreen mode is successfully engaged, the document which
> contains the document receives a mozfullscreenchange event. **When
> fullscreen mode is exited, the document again receives a
> mozfullscreenchange event**. Note that the mozfullscreenchange event
> doesn't provide any information itself as to whether the document is
> entering or exiting fullscreen mode, **but if the document has a non
> null mozFullScreenElement, you know you're in fullscreen mode**.
>
> — [MDN: Using fullscreen mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FUsing_full_screen_mode)

Here is a list of vendor prefixes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9775411/603003

Answer (score 0):

Well, removing the button was actually not the best idea. The following code works just fine to enter and leave fullscreen mode:

```
/* init fullscreen mode */
function initFullscreen() {
    $('#fullscreen').on('click', function(e) {
        toggleFullscreen();
    });
}

function toggleFullscreen() {
    if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    
        !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement) {  
        if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
            document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
        $('#fullscreen').text('Leave Fullscreen');
    } 
    else {
        if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
            document.cancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        }
        $('#fullscreen').text('Fullscreen Mode');
    }
}
```

Works as well on Android.