# fullscreenchange event not firing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, fullscreen

I'm trying to monitor when the browser enters fullscreen mode.

This blog is referenced everywhere I search as the guide on the fullscreen API.

http://robertnyman.com/2012/03/08/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/

This SO answer also claims this works.

[Fullscreen API: Which events are fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621499/fullscreen-api-which-events-are-fired)

Here is my code with jQuery, but it's not firing the event.

```
$(document).on("webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange",function(){
        console.log("bang!");
});
```

Seems simple enough, but it doesn't fire in Chrome. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Discovered something new. The events are working only if JavaScript calls the `requestFullScreen` API, but not if the user presses **F11**.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`fullscreenchange` events do work, but only if the fullscreen mode is triggered by `requestFullscreen`.

There appears to be a security restriction that prevents JavaScript from monitoring if a user manually enables fullscreen mode via a hotkey.

Alternatively, you can monitor the resize events to see if the window matches the desktop size, but this seems like a hack to me (i.e. would this work on dual-monitors?)

I decided to abandon monitoring of fullscreen mode, and just use the API to toggle the state.

Comment: `document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
 if(e.key == "F11") e.preventDefault();
});`

works only when going to full screen.
When exiting full screen doesn't work.
(In Google Chrome)

I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

As an alterative, [onresize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize) event or [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) should also work.

```js
let field = document.getElementById('textarea');

field.addEventListener('resize', (event) =>
{
    console.log(1, event);
});

let resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries =>
{
    for (let entry of entries)
    {
        console.log(2, entry);
    }
});

resizeObserver.observe(field);
```

The following one is usually **not recommended** - overwrites the global event, hence [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

```
window.onresize = function(event)
{
    console.log(1, event);
};
```

Related: [*JavaScript window resize event...*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/641857/5113030)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 120 also apparently doesn't fire events for prefixed versions like `webkitRequestFullScreen()` and the capitalized-S version: `requestFullScreen()`, but does for the standardized spelling and capitalization: `requestFullscreen()`. I filed http://crbug.com/1511367