# Is there a way to know if the navigator is fullscreen (F11)

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, navigator

In javascript, Is there a way to know if the navigator is fullscreen ? 
I mean real fullscreen (F11 with chrome).

I need to propose it to the user only if he hasn't done it yet.

Comment: `if (window.innerHeight == screen.height)` comes to mind, but it's probably not very accurate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103478/fullscreenchange-event-not-firing-in-chrome

Comment: There's no native API to check if the navigator is in fullscreen mode ... but you have the fullscreenEnabled method that return true if the context object and all ancestor browsing context's documents have their fullscreen enabled flag set ... if it returns false there must be an element in FS mode (or not?).

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#api

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode

Comment: you can use css to hide the button in non-fullscreen: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen

Answer (score -1):

For new browsers, this will work

```
function isFullScreen(){
    return (!window.screenTop && !window.screenY) 
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this works. I always get true. In fullscreen and in not fullscreen.

Comment: What browser do you have?

Comment: tells me true in chrome from the console, non-maximized.