# Revert back the size of div fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a button then when clicked, trigger the browser to go in fullscreen then it would make a certain div with an id `fScreen` get `width:100%` and `height:100%`.

When I click the <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd> button, the browser gets back to normal size but the div `fScreen` is already occupying the whole space. In my case the orginal size of `fScreen` is

```
width: 1100px;
height: 500px;
```

What I did so far was use a keydown function that reverts back the css of the `fScreen` back to the original size so far here is my code and it does not revert it back to its normal size.

```
function mkFull() //make fullscreen
{       
        //fScreen DIV
        var elem = document.getElementById("fScreen");

        if (elem.requestFullscreen) 
        {
          elem.requestFullscreen();
        } 
        else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) 
        {
          elem.msRequestFullscreen();
        } 
        else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) 
        {
          elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } 
        else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) 
        {
          elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }

        $('#fScreen').css({'width' : '100%' , 'height' : '85%'});
        isfull = 1;

}

    $(document).keydown(function(e) //when pressed esc and f11 revert back to original size
    {
        if (e.keyCode == 122 || e.keyCode == 27) 
        {   
            if(isfull == 1)
            {
                $('#fScreen').css({'width' : '100px' , 'height' : '500px'});
                isfull = 0;
            }   
        } 
    });
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to make the width `100px` when `esc` is pressed or it is a typo? `$('#fScreen').css({'width' : '100px' , 'height' : '500px'});`

Comment: i just set it to 100px for trial purposes :)

Comment: ok, and variable `isfull` is defined globally, right?

Comment: maybe it would be better if you've used $(window).on('resize', somefunction); event? (window.onresize).

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765389/html5-fullscreen-event-listener

Answer (score 1):

You could listen to the `fullscreenchange` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/fullscreenchange

In the handler, keep the state of the screen (`isFull`)

HTML

```
<button id="btn">Fullscreen</button>
<div id="fScreen">fscreen</div>
```

JS

```
    var elem = document.getElementById('fScreen');
    var isFull = false;

    function mkFull() {
        //fScreen DIV
        var elem = document.getElementById("fScreen");

        if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
            elem.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
            elem.msRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', function(e) {
        isFull = !isFull;

        if (isFull) {
            elem.style = 'width: 100%; height: 85%; background: green;';
        } else {
            elem.style = 'width: 100px; height: 500px; background: red;';
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', mkFull);
```