# Restrain fullscreen mode exit based on password (prompt())

Tags: javascript, browser

I am trying to develop a simple script that restrains if the user can or cannot leave fullscreen mode, based on password prompt. Its main objective is to avoid visitors of a museum using the interactive device for other purposes other than its primary goal, which is a browser app that teaches some things about the things exposed there, hence why I am trying to write this script in JS.

So I have created a simple code, which basically should listen to the event `fullscreenchange` and act based on that, but that's where I am facing my biggest problem: it apparently doesn't.

What it does basically is:
 - Check if fullscreenchange was called;
 - If it was, see if the user is trying to enter or leave fullscreen mode;
 - If the user is leaving fullscreen mode, ask them to enter a password;
 - If the password is incorrect, it should enable fullscreen mode again.

Take a look at what I have for now:

```
        document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function() {
            fullscreenchange();
        });

        document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function() {
            fullscreenchange();
        });

        document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function() {
            fullscreenchange();
        });

        document.addEventListener("msfullscreenchange", function() {
            fullscreenchange();
        });

        function fullscreenchange() {
            var fullscreen = (window.fullScreen) || (window.innerWidth == screen.width && window.innerHeight == screen.height);
            if(!fullscreen) 
            {
                if(!passwordChecks()){
                    openFullscreen()
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        function openFullscreen() {
            if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
            elem.requestFullscreen();
            } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
            elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
            elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
            } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
            elem.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
        }

        function passwordChecks(){
            var pass = prompt("Enter password to leave fullscreen:");

            if(pass == "leave123")
                return true;

            return false;
        }
```

The script doesn't return any errors on console (using DevTools from Chrome). But it also doesn't work, when you try to leave fullscreen, nothing happens, that's why I mentioned the `fullscreenchange` event is apparently not working.

Please let me know if there is any error in this code, and what can be done to achieve the final goal. It is simple, I hope, but I really need your help, guys.

Thank you.

Comment: Rather than trying to use JavaScript, launch the browser itself in kiosk mode. see [SU: Running latest Chrome for Windows in kiosk mode](https://superuser.com/q/716426/252695)

Comment: JavaScript can't do this, for security reasons. It would allow someone to create a website that traps you in a full-screen window.

Comment: All browsers have Kiosk Mode exactly for this reason.

Comment: fullscreenchange events do work, but only if the fullscreen mode is triggered by requestFullScreen : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103478/fullscreenchange-event-not-firing-in-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Check this, it may be useful: https://medium.com/@andreas.schallwig/building-html5-kiosk-applications-with-vue-js-and-electron-c64ac928b59f. You just need to use the "kiosk" mode