# Reload page using Jquery/JS when Mac Safari goes full screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, osx-mavericks

I have to refresh a web page whenever Mac Safari goes full screen by clicking on expand button as in the screenshot attached.

[image]

Please keep in mind that I already tried `resize` and `fullscreen` event but doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fullscreen API: Which events are fired?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621499/fullscreen-api-which-events-are-fired)

Comment: Yup, I already tried this but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Not a proper solution, but here is a workaround:

```
function reloadWhenFullScreen ( ) {
   // if it is full screen
   if ( !window.screenTop && !window.screenY ) {
      window.location.reload();
   }

   window.setTimeout(reloadWhenFullScreen, 1000);
}

reloadWhenFullScreen();
```