# How do I check for a fullscreen request on a html5 video in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I want to do something when the user clicks on the fullscreen button (bottom right hand corner) in a html5 video.

So something like this:

```
$('#video').on('webkitRequestFullscreen', function()      {       
    console.log("hello");
});
```

but this isn't working.

This will be run in an Android WebView so you don't have to worry about multiple browsers.

Comment: I aware of the function, but I also thought there was an event too. For example, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) shows elem.requestFullscreen without parens in a if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** There are events to handle this, see the following: [Fullscreen API: Which events are fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621499/fullscreen-api-which-events-are-fired)

**Original answer**
In this case you have to use an interval of some sort. Here's how I accomplished this:

```
// Returns true if we can enter fullscreen 
//(i.e. fullscreen function is available and not already fullscreened)

var canFullscreen = function(){
  return (
    !document.fullscreenElement &&
    !document.mozFullScreenElement &&
    !document.webkitFullscreenElement &&
    !document.msFullscreenElement );
}

setInterval(function(){
  if( canFullscreen() ) {
    // Handle exiting fullscreen
  } else {
    // Handle entering fullscreen
  }
}, 50);
```